# How to structure Blazor Server Side App to have up to date information with folders of CSVs as the Data Source?

Tags: memory-leaks, blazor, blazor-server-side

To give the brief introduction, I'm new to Blazor. I could very well be missing an obvious feature.

Project assigned is requesting a Blazor, Server Side Application to display charts of information retrieved from 10 accessible system folders, each with hourly CSVs, the last of which adds a row of data every 1-3 seconds. Once the hour has passed, a new CSV is created, and we continue, ad infinitum for purposes of this argument. Each CSV has 100 columns; we're only focusing on 3 for now. If the argument of SQL comes up, they do not want to upload anywhere from 1 to 1.5 million rows to SQL each day. CSVs currently have anywhere from 1500 to 7200 rows of data.

Currently, page loads, data chunk is retrieved, in this case the last 4 hours, and then every 5 seconds, data from the last two files is retrieved (to avoid missing any hour turnover rows), and only new data is added to the data source in the site. The Date Timestamp of each row is treated as unique for each cluster. The charts only show the last 15 to 30 minute of a rolling buffer of activity for demo purposes, though they may very well request longer

Read access to CSVs is not a concern. All methods to access CSVs are wrapped in using statements. My concern is, in this program's infancy, each client opening the page reinitiates the data retrieval and background looper, and that means we effectively have no scalability, and the process memory is just an upward slope.

What are my actions to reduce server load, if there are any? Should I push harder for SQL based?

Comment: It would be possible to keep in memory (maybe some singleton service) just one copy of data that would be shared between clients. But I’m still not sold on the idea of manipulating and managing all the csvs for charting purposes. Are you sure your app is not reinventing the wheel? Have you thought about something like elastic and kibana?

Answer (score 0):

OK, some thoughts and ideas.  I'm reading a bit between the lines here, so forgive me if I'm way off the mark. (Sounds a bit like a NHS COVID dashboard app, they love their spreadsheets!)

What the customer wants is a front end that "reacts" i.e. redraws from new data, when new data arrives.  So that's an event driven update (either time or when a new entry is made).  This event can be detected in the backend by detecting file updates. `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher` comes to mind.  That drives a new read of the updated file, refresh of the Service data set and trigger of an event in the service.  Use a Singleton backend data service - to get the data. Any users with an open SPA session register with the event (probably through a scoped or transient controller service), which precipitates a UI update.

A SQL solution I'm sure will work better, but you don't often get to choose!